# Is Rails version 3.1.1 compatible with Ruby version 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am in a situation where I need to update several API-connected gems that are no longer supported by my current version of Ruby. (1.9.3) The Rails release notes for Rails version 3.1.1 state that Rails 3.1 requires Ruby 1.8.7 or higher but it's hard to tell if that includes versions of Ruby which might have been updated more recently than the release notes.

Am I good to update to 2.3 on my Rails 3.1.1 app?

Comment: Well if you use RVM you can just try it and see. The official docs don't specify a max ruby version.

Answer (score 2):

Form the [release notes](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/2/27/Rails-3-2-13-rc1-has-been-released/) of Ruby on Rails 3.2.13:

> There is one big thing that is technically a fix but is sort of a feature: Ruby 2.0 support. Big thanks to Prem Sichanugrist for putting that together! Please give your applications a try on Ruby 2.0 and let me know how that goes.

That said: When Rails 3.2.13 was the first version of Rails with Ruby 2.0 support then it is unlikely that the older Rails 3.1.1 version is working with Ruby 2.3.